# Is it possible to control the order results are returned using default_scope with created_at time from another table in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I have message threads and on a users inbox page I show the username and part of the message of the other participant of the conversation.

In my methodthread model I have:

```
default_scope :order => 'message_threads.updated_at DESC'
```

I realised this isn't what I need. I need the to grab the created_at time from my messages table. So that every time a new message is added to a message_thread it brings that message thread to the top of the list.

Just so you have a better understanding I have these tables:

**messages** (I use acts as tree plugin to created children and a parent for each conversation. E.G. Parent_id is the primary id of the message and that primary id becomes the children's parent_id's.)

**message_threads** (I use this table to reference conversations so here I look for sender_id and recipient_id with a message_id that has a null parent_id. This confirms that message is a parent and has children.)

Anyway what would be the best way to do what I'm trying to do which is control the order the results of method_threads table are returned buy using the created_at times of the messages table?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear order that you get from default_scope and order you query by joined table, something like this:

```
MessageThreads.except(:order).joins(:message).order("messages.created_at DESC").
```

Also, you can use method unscoped to clear default_scope if you wish.

Comment: I'm thinking another way to do this would be to update have the message thread updated at column updated every time a new message is sent or received in my messages table. This way I can use my current code to display threads. What do you think?